# Query for all users except for users with an ID in this collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to find all users except for users with an id that is a member of an array `exclude_ids`

Here's what I have:

```
User.where("id != ?", exclude_ids)
```

This only works when exclude_ids has only 1 element. If it has more than one element, I get

this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near ",": syntax error: SELECT     "users".* FROM       "users" WHERE     (id != 1,2)
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Why not check if `"id != ?", nil` or something along those lines?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I havent used Rails 3 but its unsafe to use `User.where("id in #{exclude_ids} ?")`.

On Rails 2.x you do it as follows

```
User.find(:all, :conditions => ["id NOT IN (?)", [1,2,3]])
```

Rails 3.x docs http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v3.0.0.beta.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: You can use the all() method instead of find(:all, …).

Answer (score 2):

```
User.where('id NOT IN (:ids)', ids: exclude_ids)  # SQL does the filtering
```

or

```
User.select { |u| exclude_ids.exclude? u.id }  # Ruby does the filtering
```

Answer (score 0):

i  am not confirm but you can Try this

User.where("id not in #{exclude_ids} ?")